# Use different constructor for class member based on class template parameter

Tags: c++, constructor, c++17, initializer-list

Have a situation where a templated class constains a templated member and said member object must be constructed using the proper constructor (which depends on a class template).  Simplified example:

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<int N=0>
struct A
{
    const int n_;

    A(int n, double)
        : n_{n}
    {
        static_assert(N <= 0);
    }

    A(double)
        : n_{N}
    {
        static_assert(N > 0);
    }
};


template<int N=0>
struct B
{
    const std::vector<int> m_;

    // Solution with unique_ptr class member to an A<N> object
    std::unique_ptr<A<N>> a_uptr_;
    B(const std::vector<int>& m, double x)
        :   m_{m},
            a_uptr_{N > 0 ? std::make_unique<A<N>>(x) : std::make_unique<A<N>>(m.size(), x)}
    {}


    // Solution with class member A<N> object
    // A<N> a_;
    // B(const std::vector<int>& m, double x)
    //  :   m_{m},
    //      a_{  <????????????????????> }
    // {}
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> m{1,2,3};
    B b1(m, 0);
    B<2> b2(m, 0); 
    std::cout << b1.a_uptr_->n_ << ", " << b2.a_uptr_->n_ << std::endl;
}
```

Q1: Is there a way to just have an `A<N>` class member (instead of a unique ptr) and have it call the correct constructor? Using an `std::integer_sequence` perhaps???

(Q2: Am I overthinking this, i.e. should I really be worried about performance of having to put the `A<N>` obj on the heap?)

Comment: You can initialize `a_` with either `A<N>(x)` or `A<N>(,.size(), x)`. Much like you already do with the pointer.

Comment: Possibly you could use *specialization* instead? What is the actual and underlying problem you try to solve? Perhaps it has different solutions?

Comment: EDIT: Sorry, the actual code for `A` does produce a compile-time error if the wrong constructor is called. So can't just initialize via the copy constructor like that.  I will change the `throw` to a `static_assert` in the question.

Comment: According to your actual aim, several solutions are possible. I'm first thinking about _tag dispatch_. You can use a template tag which would be different for N <= 0 and N > 0, and pass it as default second argument of the `A` constructor. Would that solve your issue?

Comment: on second thought, according to N the signature is already not the same...

Comment: If you can modify `A`, you may use postponed construction: you default construct the `A` object, then, in `B` constructor, you use if `constexpr` to call an initialisation member function for `A`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the question is only about `B`, that `A` is supposed to not change...
Then what you face is what I would call "complicated construction of a member in the initializer list" and the soltuion for this is generally a static method:

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<int N=0>
struct A {
    const int n_;   
    A(int n, double) : n_{n} {
        if constexpr (N > 0) throw  std::runtime_error("wrong constructor for N > 0");
    }

    A(double) : n_{N} {
        if constexpr (N <= 0) throw std::runtime_error("wrong constructor for N <= 0");
    }
};


template<int N=0>
struct B {
    const std::vector<int> m_;    
    A<N> a_uptr_;
    B(const std::vector<int>& m, double x) 
      :   m_{m},
          a_uptr_{make_AN(m,x)}
    {}
private:
    static A<N> make_AN(const std::vector<int>& m,double x) {
        if constexpr (N>0) return x;
        else return {m.size(),x};
    }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<int> m{1,2,3};
    B b1(m, 0);
    B<2> b2(m, 0); 
    std::cout << b1.a_uptr_.n_ << ", " << b2.a_uptr_.n_ << std::endl;
}
```

Or as mentioned in comments (Some programmer dude and n.m.), simply `a_{N > 0 ? A<N>{m} : A<N>{m, x}}`. Perhaps you are afraid of copies which are elided anyhow.

However, you should consider to rewrite `A` such that it is a compile time error to call `A<N>::A(int,double)` with `N > 0` and `A<N>::A(double)` with `N <= 0`.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number, I'm surprised by the `return` statements in `make_AN`. Can you detail the mechanism that make the compiler use an adequate constructor. In particular, the second one looks like an implicit conversion from `std::initializer_list` to `A<N>`, which is not defined, thus I must be wrong.

Comment: @Oersted https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization case (8)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number, Thx, in order to get it right case (8) is saying that  ̀return {m.size(),x} ̀ is actually the same as `A<N>{m.size(),x}` and  ̀̀̀{m.size(),x}` is not an `std::initializer_list` (which allows for mixing types). Am I right?